# In a routing and scheduling problem with break consideration, How can I determine whether a node is met before a break or after it?

Tags: optimization, mixed-integer-programming, modeling, scheduling, vehicle-routing

I'm working on a routing and scheduling problem in the home care services context. I consider a break as a dummy patient, so routing and scheduling are also implemented for the break node (with some conditions). For some reason, I need to determine whether a visit occurs before or after a break. I defined two binary variables: $Z(i,k,t)$ which means if patient i is visited by doctor k on shift t **before** the break, and $Z'(i,k,t)$ for **after** the break. I added 2 new constraints as follows:

$S(b,k,t)-S(i,k,t) =l= M* Z(i,k,t)$

$Z(i,k,t) + Z'(i,k,t) =l= \sum_j X(i,j,k,t)$

$S(b,k,t)$ is the starting time of break by doctor k on shift t

$S(i,k,t)$ is the starting time of visiting patient i by doctor k on shift t

$X(i,j,k,t)$ is if doctor k on shift t goes from node i to node j (binary variable)

In the first constraint, if the left-hand side becomes positive, $Z(i,k,t)$ will be 1.
The second one is guaranteeing that Z and Z' could get value if patient i was visited by doctor k on shift t.
By adding these 2 constraints to my model, the result of my S variables (starting time) get wrong.
I think it's better to rewrite the first constraint so that it becomes related somehow to $X(i,j,k,t)$, but I can not figure out how to do it.

Comment: This video on [how to deal with lunch breaks in VRP](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4dM9fcknEhE) might be useful. Start from the 2:25 mark in the video.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use binary $x_{i,j}^{k,t}=1$ if $k$ visits any node (patient or break node) basically the connecting edge (between patient -break and break-patient) and just one set of binary $z_{i}^{k,t}$ to indicate if doctor has visited patient $i$ or break $b$
Let $P$ is set of patients & $B$ is set of break nodes with $I = P \cup B$ set of all nodes

Constraints
$ s_{i}^{k,t} \le Mz_i^{k,t}$

$ z_i^{k,t} \le \sum_jx_{i,j}^{k,t}+\sum_i x_{j,i}^{k,t} - 1$

$ \sum_i x_{i,j}^{k,t} \le Mz_i^{k,t}$

$ \sum_jx_{i,j}^{k,t} - \sum_i x_{i,j}^{k,t} = 0$

$ M(x_{i,j}^{k,t}-1) \le s_{j}^{k,t} - s_{i}^{k,t} \le Mx_{i,j}^{k,t}$

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason why you want to adjust your model? I would try to not add complexity to your mathematical model, as the solution to your initial problem should already include all the information you need, so I would rather see it as an information extraction issue. For example, if you use the Miller-Tucker-Zemlin formulation for subtour elimination purposes, you could use it to determine if a patient is visited before a break or afterward. I.e., you could simply look at the auxiliary variables (often referred to as $u_i$). If $u_i < u_j$, $i$ is visited before $j$.